# Create array of values from sub-table

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join, plpgsql

For example I have table `users`(id, name, email). There is table `photos` (id, value)
There is a table `userphotos` which consists of relations:
user_id, photo_id.

I need a function to fetch all users with their photos in such a way:

> 1. id1 name1 email1 photos1
> 2. id2 name2 email2 photos2

etc.

Number of photos for a user is not known.

How to create plpgsql function to create such results?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function()
  RETURNS TABLE(id int, name character varying, email character varying,  photos int[]) AS $
DECLARE
    u RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR u IN SELECT * FROM users LOOP
        return NEXT u; -- will return user without photos
    -- but how to populate u with photos as array
    -- got from query:
    --          SELECT photo_id FROM userphotos WHERE user_id = u.id
    END LOOP;
END;
$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

PostgreSQL ver. 9.0.

Comment: Define "photos1" in the result. Do you one row per `userphotos` in the result or one list of photos per user? Represented by `id` or `value`?. Where does `partners` in the function come from? Add your version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Sorry, 'partners' was from another example. I've corrected and added posgresql version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function()
  RETURNS TABLE(id int, name varchar, email varchar, photos int[]) AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, array_agg(up.photo_id)  -- AS photo_ids
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN userphotos up ON  up.user_id = u.id
GROUP  BY u.int, u.name, u.email;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

- Use proper quoting. Read the manual about [dollar-quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).
- Use [`RETURN QUERY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) as simplest way to return rows from a plpgsql function. No `LOOP` necessary.
- The `LEFT JOIN` includes users who have no photos at all.
- Beware of naming conflicts. All `OUT` parameters in the `RETURNS TABLE` clause are visible in the body everywhere.

---

#### Addendum after comment

If you want to join *multiple* 1:n tables, you can't join them all at once. This is what'd happen:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860

Another closely related answer with a solution for this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110017/939860

Comment: Thank you. It works. But I have problems if I have to do more than one JOIN. For example I also have to fetch user groups for every user from table `usergroups`. I add one more LEFT JOIN and I got duplicating results in array_agg(up.photo_id) column

Comment: Thank you very much! Grouping inside JOIN it's what I needed